# Assembly cannot be loaded on runtime if a package was installed with nuget

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

My main problem is how to do a dependency injection on MVC5, Api and a DB repository layer. For this after some amount of search I have reached [this website](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/829/dependency-injection-ninject-aspnet-mvc)

I got the project code from gitHub and moved the code to VS2013 and Ninject.MVC5. The Ninject is installed with nuGet and it is installed in FunWithSignalR.Data and FunWithSignalR.CompositionRoot.
All went good until I have hit run button. The project does build successfully but on run-time An issue is raised that assembly FunWithSignalR.Data can't be loaded. The assemblies are loaded like this:

```
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            Assembly
                .Load("FunWithSignalR.Domain"),
            Assembly
                .Load("FunWithSignalR.Data"),
            Assembly
                .Load("FunWithSignalR.CompositionRoot"));
```

I saw that the error `"Could not load file or assembly 'FunWithSignalR.Data' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"FunWithSignalR.Data"` is present only present for projects in which I have installed Ninject.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you added FunWithSignalR.Data as a reference into the ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: @Vinod Yes I've done it